# Errorbar whiskers. width argument of geom_errorbar interferes with width argument of position = "dodge"

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to change the widht of the geom_errorbar() 'whiskers' of the following ggplot.
In my eyes it seems like a bug. The usual `width = x` specification for the errorbars does not work here. it interferes with the `width = x` specification of the `position = "dodge` argument. Is there any way i can specify that `width = x` is only for geom_errorbars?

```
 library(tidyverse)
    
    
    
    data <- as_tibble(rbind(c("out", 14, 2.3,T),
                            c("in", 15, 2.7,T),
                            c("far", 18, 4,T),
                            c("out", 14, 2.3, F),
                            c("in", 17, 2.3, F),
                            c("far", 13, 2.3, F)
                            )
                      )
    colnames(data) <- c("position", "mean", "se", "dead")
    data$mean <- as.numeric(as.character(data$mean))
    data$se <- as.numeric(as.character(data$se))
    
    data
    
    ggplot(data = data, aes(x = position, y = mean, fill = dead)) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se),
                    stat = "identity",
                    position = "dodge", 
                    width = 3)+                              # its about this line !
      geom_bar(stat = "identity",
               position = "dodge")
```

This is the plot given out by the code above:

[image]

the errorbars are all over the place. without the `width = x` specification they are where they should be, but i would like them to be smaller !

Comment: Please read the help text. From the examples: "Because the bars and errorbars have different widths we need to specify how wide the objects we are dodging are
`dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)`.

Comment: OP :  think of is this way.  The width of the geom is the distance across for one geom (bar or whisker here).  The *width of the dodge* can be set independent of that by using `position=position_dodge(width=...)`.  Using `position="dodge"` sets the width of the dodge to be equal to the width of the geom.  So this means when you change the width of the error bar, the dodge width also changes.  Your solution is to specify the same width *of the dodge* via `position=position_dodge()` for both geoms to be the same, then you can specify different widths for each geom.